# NAS server smartd.conf assistance

Tags: linux, backup, nas, smartctl, smartmontools

I want to perform the following using smartd:
Run short smartctl test once a week.
Run long smartctl test once a month.
Get the results for each run on mail.

I tried to read the 'man' page for both smartd and smartd.conf (https://linux.die.net/man/5/smartd.conf), but I just can't seem to understand it. Maybe I'm just dumb, but I can't understand anything from their examples...

E.g:

```
#
# Three disks connected to a MegaRAID controller
# Start short self-tests daily between 1-2, 2-3, and
# 3-4 am.
  /dev/sda -d megaraid,0 -a -s S/../.././01
  /dev/sda -d megaraid,1 -a -s S/../.././02
  /dev/sda -d megaraid,2 -a -s S/../.././03
```

That doesn't make any sense to me, and I can't understand how to apply that to my use case.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to be a bit more specific what precisely you don't understand. I assume that your problem is the date-and-time expression that comes after `-s`.

In the expression `T/MM/DD/d/HH`, the T is either `S` for a short test or `L` for a long one.

The rest of the string is date and time, and since this is a regular expression, the wildcard is a dot. Thus `S/../../1/00` means a short test on any date, Monday at 00 hours, and `L/../01/./00` is a long test on the first day of any month.

The `-d` option tells `smartd` the device type. `auto` should be fine in most cases; however, only you know what type of storage devices you have.

To send email, add `-m displainame@somewhere.com`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you were totally right, understanding WHAT is the actual expression makes it much more clear to me and that was what I didn't understand.

Comment: I'd like to get some further assistance if possible.
I've set up my smartd.conf file like this:

/dev/sda -a -m something@gmail.com -M test
/dev/sda -a -d auto -m something@gmail.com -s S/../.././03
/dev/sda -a -d auto -m something@gmail.com -s S/../.././04
/dev/sda -a -d auto -m something@gmail.com -s L/../.././05

As far as I understand this should run between 3-6 in the morning. I did receive the test email, but I didn't receive the others, not even sure if they ran. Do you see anything wrong in the config I used?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks good to me, but I don't know anything about `smartd`. It should do some logging to the system log, and it seems you can add the `-r` option to make it log more. Another thought: Did you restart `smartd`?